# python en una tabla como unir celdas

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx

estuve buscando todo el día pero no encuentro que librería debo utilizar para poder crear una tabla en docx con estas dimensiones :

`tabla =  [ celda(0,0) - celda(0,1)] # unidas
          [celda (1,0)] [celda(1,1)]
          [celda (2,0) - celda(2,1)] #  unidas
          [celda (3,0)] [celda(3,1)]`

Que las filas (0) estén unidas, filas (1) separadas, etc
Espero puedan ayudarme
Quiero ingresar los valores de las celdas a través de una Lista y hasta ahora estoy utilizando la librería Docx sin muchos resultados

Comment: ¿Cómo se relacionan las etiquetas `python` y `docx` de tu pregunta? ¿Estás usando alguna biblioteca o framework de creación de documentos Word desde python? ¿Cuál?

Comment: Quiero usar una Lista para ingresar los valores a las celdas y hasta ahora estoy usando la librería docx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo con la [documentación de python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) puedes mezclar celdas mediante el método `.merge` de una celda (pasándole como parámetro otra celda, y juntará en una sola todas las celdas comprendidas entre ambas).

No está claro lo que quieres hacer, a partir del código que proporcionas, porque no es código python válido y no se entiende tampoco como pseudocódigo.

Pero por si te sirve de orientación, aquí tienes una posible implementación de la idea. Tenemos una lista con los contenidos de cada fila:

```
contenidos = [
    [ "Contenido de la primera fila" ],
    [ "Contenido de la", "segunda fila" ],
    [ "Contenido de la tercera fila" ],
    [ "Contenido de la", "cuarta fila" ]
]
```

Como ves, es una lista compuesta de sub-listas. En estas sub-listas algunas tienen un solo elemento y otras tienen dos. La idea es que las que tengan un solo elemento darán lugar a dos celdas unidas en una, mientras que las que tienen dos mantendrán dos celdas separadas.

El siguiente código crearía una tabla así:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

contenidos = [
    [ "Contenido de la primera fila" ],
    [ "Contenido de la", "segunda fila" ],
    [ "Contenido de la tercera fila" ],
    [ "Contenido de la", "cuarta fila" ]
]


table = document.add_table(rows=0, cols=2)
for fila in contenidos:
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    row_cells[0].text = fila[0]
    if len(fila) == 1:
        row_cells[0].merge(row_cells[1])
    else:
        row_cells[1].text = fila[1]

document.add_page_break()
document.save('demo.docx')
```

Este es el aspecto del documento al abrirlo en Word:

[image: Resultado]

**Nota**. En el estilo por defecto con que la tabla es creada, no hay bordes entre celdas. Se los he añadido después desde Word para que se vea claramente las que están unidas y las que no.

Comment: muchas gracias pero ahora tengo otro problema... copié y pegué tu código amigo pero no me sale las líneas de las tablas, solo el contenido   
Contenido de la primera fila
Contenido de la segunda fila
Contenido de la tercera fila
Contenido de la cuarta fila
Hay alguna opción que debo habilitar en Word?

Comment: muchas gracias pero tengo otro problema al abrir el documento word no me aparecen las lineas de la tabla, la tabla si existe pero las lineas no, tengo que habilitar algo en MS Word? copié y pegué tu mismo código. espero puedas ayudarme con esto último ya que en ningún código que ingreso me salen las lineas

Comment: @CelestHaku Ya te lo había aclarado en una nota al final de la respuesta :-) De todas formas, por lo que he visto, puedes hacer que salgan las líneas si pones `table = document.add_table(rows=0, cols=2, style='Table Grid')` al crear la tabla. También he visto que en ese caso las filas salen más estrechas, pero eso ya no sé cómo arreglarlo. Tendrías que mirar en la documentación, a ver si hay forma de definir estilos. Yo no conozco bien esta librería.

Comment: Muchas gracias me has ayudado mucho