# python3 docx darle forma a una tabla

Tags: python-3.x, tablas, docx

Buenas tardes me habían ayudado con la creación de una tabla pero quisiera darle una forma con el ancho de las celdas

```
contenidos = [
        ["registro de la comunicacion"],
        ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e"],
        ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
        ["objetivos"],
        ["numero", "imsi", "imei"],
        ["a", "b", "c"],
```

Lo único que deseo unir es en la fila1 y fila2 respectivamente, que tienen 5 celdas, quisiera unir sus celdas y formar 2 celdas (a, b) (c, d, e) para que quede así.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: O en su defecto como puedo crear una tabla de esas dimensiones. Muchas gracias

Comment: CelestHaku, te sugiero revisar este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/278855/python-en-una-tabla-como-unir-celdas

Answer (score 0):

Hasta ahora lo mejor que he podido hacer es crear tablas individuales y manejar sus dimensiones a mi antojo. Espero esta sea la respuesta

```
table0 = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=1, style='Table 
Grid')
table0.cell(0, 0).width = Inches(9.0)

table1 = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=2, style='Table 
Grid')
table1.cell(0, 0).width = Inches(3.0)
table1.cell(0, 1).width = Inches(6.0)

table2 = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=2, style='Table 
Grid')
table2.cell(0, 0).width = Inches(3.0)
table2.cell(0, 1).width = Inches(6.0)
```

He podido darle formato a mis necesidades.